# Is there a way to make the mouse cursor easier to see?

Tags: terraria

I keep losing my mouse cursor in big fights with lots of projectiles.  Is there a way to make the mouse cursor stand out more?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**, you can change the `ThickMouseEdges` property in the `config.json` file from `false` to `true` to make the cursor have a thick border around the mouse on screen.

[image: Cursor border comparison]

You can find your `config.json` file under your `My Games\Terraria` folder in Windows.  The full path would be:

### Windows

`C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\Documents\My Games\Terraria\config.json`

### OSX

`/Users/<USER_NAME>/Library/Application Support/Terraria/config.json`

`<USER_NAME>` should of course be changed to your system's user name. Linux and OSX are currently in beta and I'm not sure where the Linux save configuration file is.

Comment: Could you show us how to find the config.json file?

Comment: @AngusAtkinson Yep, and I'll try to figure out where the files are on OSX and Linux

Comment: Just a note to anyone else coming here. If you see Terraria stuff in `~/My Games/` in Mac or Linux, delete it. It's a remnant from early beta and Terraria changed it's map/character/config location to the one listed in this answer. When it changed, the game left the files it created in `~/My Games` behind, but they aren't used anymore. Confused the crap out of me when trying to import/export my worlds.

Comment: Since v1.3.1, you can configure the mouse border (color, transparency) from the settings of the main menu.

Comment: honestly this isn't much improvement... the cursor went from tiny to slightly less tiny. I can change my Windows cursor to be HUGE, but it doesn't affect the Terraria cursor in the slightest!